# É possível executar 2 comandos(delete,Insert) em uma Stored Procedure - MYSQL?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, mysql

Caindo na condição do `if` preciso executar esses dois comandos:

```
if(ultima_refeicao!=refeicao) then
 SELECT refeicao_alimentos.calorias into calorias from refeicao_alimentos where refeicao_alimentos.id_Usuario=usuario ORDER BY  refeicao_alimentos.idRefeicao  desc limit 1;
 SELECT refeicao_alimentos.carboidrato into carboidratos from refeicao_alimentos where refeicao_alimentos.id_Usuario=usuario ORDER BY  refeicao_alimentos.idRefeicao  desc limit 1;
 SELECT refeicao_alimentos.proteina into proteinas from refeicao_alimentos where refeicao_alimentos.id_Usuario=usuario ORDER BY  refeicao_alimentos.idRefeicao  desc limit 1;
 SELECT refeicao_alimentos.gordura into gorduras from refeicao_alimentos where refeicao_alimentos.id_Usuario=usuario ORDER BY  refeicao_alimentos.idRefeicao  desc limit 1;

delete from refeicao_alimentos where refeicao_alimentos.idRefeicao=refeicao and refeicao_alimentos.id_Usuario=usuario;

insert into refeicao_alimentos_log(id_Usuario,refeicoes,alimento,porcao,calorias,carboidrato,proteina,gordura,dia,metas_calorias,metas_carboidratos,metas_proteinas,metas_gorduras,desabilitar) values
(usuario,refeicao,1,0,0,0,0,0,curdate(),1,1,1,1,"s");
```

Comment: é possível ....

Comment: Com os dados da pergunta o que dá para responder é com um código hipotético que mostra a estrutura de declaração do `PROCEDURE` e do `IF/END IF` mas provavelmente não vai funcionar com o seu banco de dados pois sem conhecer o esquema das tabelas envolvidas não dá para montar um código específico ao seu projeto. Se lhe servir um código hipotético avise pois já tenho ele pronto mas se quiser algo funcional edite a pergunta e coloque o esquema das tabelas.

Comment: Sim, por favor.O código hipotético vai ajudar sim...